# sending mail with mail.live.com fails on production server

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

I've a simple script to send MailMessage emails.  This works and sends emails running locally.  However when deployed to production server I get this error

```
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web    request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it  originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. >Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Mail code:

```
try
{
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;
   smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
   smtp.Send(message);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Config settings:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="support@domain.com">
       <network host="smtp.live.com" password="password" port="587" userName="support@domain.com"  enableSsl="true"/>
     </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Any ideas why it fails in production?

NB the same code worked when using Gmail (after changing port and host config settings)

Comment: I think it's a problem with the SSL certificate on the server. See if [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/00f54d4f-5d83-4537-a222-128c89584737/) or [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/b1ba71ec-499a-44a0-81de-6165c660b80a/) helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SSL certificate on webserver resolved the issue.